# Difficult nested dictionary to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

This is my annoying nested dictionary:

```
 "data": [

{
 'type': 'a',
 'id': '3',
 'attributes': {'name': 'Alexander',
  'address': 'Ree 25',
  'postalCode': '3019 VM',
  'place': 'Amsterdam',
  'company': 'Pizza BV',
  'phoneNumbers': [{'description': 'general', 'phoneNumber': '+31104136911'}],
  'locationCode': 'DURTM',
  'website': 'http://www.pizzabv.nl',
  'primaryEmail': 'info@pizzabv.nl',
  'secondaryEmail': '',
  'geoLocation': {'type': 'Point',
    'coordinates': [16.309702884655767, 31.879930329139634]
 }
},
 'relationships': [],
 'links': {'self': 'www.homepage.nl'
  }
},

{
 'type': 'b',
 'id': '7',
 'attributes': {'name': 'Sam',
  'address': 'Zee 15',
  'postalCode': '2019 AM',
  'place': 'Groningen',
  'company': 'Salami BV',
  'phoneNumbers': [{'description': 'specific', 'phoneNumber': '+31404136121'}],
  'locationCode': 'SWSTM',
  'website': 'http://www.salamibv.nl',
  'primaryEmail': 'info@salamibv.nl',
  'secondaryEmail': '',
  'geoLocation': {'type': 'Point',
   'coordinates': [18.309702884655767, 34.879930329139634]
 }
},
 'relationships': [],
 'links': {'self': 'www.homepage.nl'
 }
}
]
```

This is how I would like to have my dataframe:

```
type | id | name | address | postalCode | ... | type | coordinates | relationships | links
...    ...   ...     ...        ...       ...    ...      ...            ...          ...
```

So different underlying dictionaries have to be moved up a layer. First **attributes** has to be deleted and underlying values has to be moved up one layer.

Also **description** and **phoneNumber** must be moved up a layer and then **phoneNumbers** can me removed.

Furthermore all information about a **type** and **id** should be placed in one row.

I don't get how to do this. I tried several methods like these:

```
terminals = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
terminals.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
terminals.head()
```

But this gives me complete dictionaries in one cell of a Pandas Dataframe.

I hope somebody can help me out a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to denest your data. You can do it with a recursive function such as:

```py
def denest(x, parent=None, d=None):
    if d is None:
        d = {}
    for k, v in x.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            denest(v, parent=(parent or []) + [k], d=d)
        elif isinstance(v, (list, tuple)):
            for j, item in enumerate(v):
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    denest(item, parent=(parent or []) + [k, j], d=d)
                else:
                     d[tuple((parent or []) + [k, j])] = item
        else:
            d[tuple((parent or []) + [k])] = v
    return d
```

Then, assuming `data` is a list of dictionaries, you can simply create a dataframe like this:

```py
pd.DataFrame([denest(i) for i in data])
```

```
  (attributes, address) (attributes, company)  (attributes, geoLocation, coordinates, 0)  (attributes, geoLocation, coordinates, 1) (attributes, geoLocation, type) (attributes, locationCode) (attributes, name) (attributes, phoneNumbers, 0, description) (attributes, phoneNumbers, 0, phoneNumber) (attributes, place) (attributes, postalCode) (attributes, primaryEmail) (attributes, secondaryEmail)   (attributes, website) (id,)    (links, self) (type,)
0                Ree 25              Pizza BV                                  16.309703                                   31.87993                           Point                      DURTM          Alexander                                    general                               +31104136911           Amsterdam                  3019 VM            info@pizzabv.nl                                http://www.pizzabv.nl     3  www.homepage.nl       a
1                Zee 15             Salami BV                                  18.309703                                   34.87993                           Point                      SWSTM                Sam                                   specific                               +31404136121           Groningen                  2019 AM           info@salamibv.nl                               http://www.salamibv.nl     7  www.homepage.nl       b
```

If you prefer, from here you can then rename columns and/or turn them into a multi-index dataframe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

define a function that parses the dictionary into the flattened structure then apply that before passing it to the dataframe constructor

```py
def parse(dict_)
    di = dict_.copy()  # weak copy the dictionary so you don't modify the original dicts

    # bring attributes up a level
    di.update(di['attributes'])
    del di['attributes']

    # etc...
    return di

df = pd.DataFrame(map(parse, data))
```